# Ionic Cordova API Authorisation 401

Tags: ios, nginx, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular9

Ionic application developed in angular 9 combination.

First i have tried with `import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';`

Worked in Web and Android, not worked in iOS, In iOS getting 401 error.

Then i integrated `import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';` and tried API call same result.

401 error

Sharing version details please help.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.6",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.4.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.23.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.21.5",
    "@ionic-native/http": "5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.21.6",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/streaming-media": "^5.21.6",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/video-player": "^5.22.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.19",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "com.moust.cordova.videoplayer": "https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-js": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.3",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^0.9.13",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-toast": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-video-player": "git+https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git",
    "cordova-plugin-video-thumbnail": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "ionic-image-loader": "^6.3.3",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.7.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "set-default-browser": "^1.1.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

Sharing header set tried different ways.

```
1. 
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'GWT token' })

2. 
    const headers_object = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json').set('Authorization', `JWT token`);

3.
    let headersnew: Headers = new Headers();
    headersnew.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headersnew.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    headersnew.set('Authorization', `JWT token`);
```

Update code snippet based on feedback, please check

Comment: You don't need `@ionic-native/http/ngx` if you use  `Angular's HttpClient`. If you get a 401 response, it probably means you are not sending the correct values in your request. Please post some code so that we can help.

Comment: Thank you your response.

 Sharing code snippet for HttpClient  header settings
```headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            })```
Its working fine in Web and Android, but not working in iOS.

Comment: That looks alright, I don't know why it wouldn't work only on iOS. Have you checked the request received server-side?

Comment: The problem is that my Authorization token is never appended to the headers. When I traced using debugger, I found that reqOpts has my appended headers in something called lazyUpdate. My http call fails as no authorization token was sent so I get an Unauthorized error.

Comment: You should post all relevant code in the question.

Comment: Thank you. Sharing more details, please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215283/discussion-between-rajesh-pillai-and-sebastien).